# switch user using python script without password prompt

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to run sudo su - command in the python script below but it is not able to read the input from the given value which is my password.

Any help would be appreciated thank you!

```
from subprocess import run
import subprocess
import os



run('ls -al', shell=True,  text=True)
run('sudo su -', shell=True,
    stdin="password")

run('cd /etc', shell=True,  text=True)
```

error

```
python3.9 -u "/home/cs/python/hey.py"
total 20
drwxrwxr-x  4 cs cs 4096 Mar 19 13:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 45 cs cs 4096 Mar 19 11:30 ..
drwxrwxr-x  4 cs cs 4096 Mar 12 22:40 dfa-to-regex
-rw-rw-r--  1 cs cs  241 Mar 19 13:38 hey.py
drwxrwxr-x  5 cs cs 4096 Mar 19 12:24 .venv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cs/python/hey.py", line 9, in <module>
    run('sudo su -', shell=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 505, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 829, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1586, in _get_handles
    p2cread = stdin.fileno()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

Comment: Passwords are usually read from the tty in "raw mode". You can't use subprocess with those. You will have to supply the password another way, or set up sudo to be passwordless for the command you want.

Comment: @Keith could you tell me the module that you would use in this scenario?
Thank you!

Comment: Actually, in the case of `sudo` there is an option the read the password from stdin stream, `-S`. I would use [my own module](https://github.com/pycopia/devtest/blob/master/devtest/os/sudo.py) to do that, however.

Comment: code you provide the command using your module @Keith? 
Thanks!

Comment: What command are you trying to run with `su`? I don't see one.

Comment: oh I'm trying to do su - which is also su root @Keith

Comment: To get an interactive shell?

Comment: Well then you will definitely have to run that through a pty. But why would you want to do that from Python?